# Conditional Drop down values population in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have two drop downs like **Group Types** and **Sub Group Types** in my UI .

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="GroupType" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Group Type: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select name="selGroupType" id="selGroupType" class="form-control" ng-change="referenceAddRecord.populateGroupTypeDetails(selGroupType)" ng-options="groupType.value for groupType in referenceAddRecord.groupTypes track by groupCode.id" ng-model="referenceAddRecord.groupType"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="SubGroupType" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label">Sub Group Type: </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select name="selSubGroupType" id="selSubGroupType" class="form-control" ng-change="referenceAddRecord.populateSubGroupTypeDetails(selSubGroupType)" ng-options="subGroupType.value for subGroupType in referenceAddRecord.subGroupTypes track by subGroupType.id" ng-model="referenceAddRecord.subGroupType"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And in my controller I am binding the values after reading from JSON file like

```
referenceDataDropDownService.getDropDown(REFERENCE_DATA_CONSTANTS.GROUP_TYPE).success(function (result) {
    $scope.referenceAddRecord.groupTypes = result;
}).error(function (result) {
    alert("Unable to retrieve dropdown values");
});

referenceDataDropDownService.getDropDown(REFERENCE_DATA_CONSTANTS.SUB_GROUP_TYPE).success(function (result) {

    $scope.referenceAddRecord.subGroupTypes = result;
}).error(function (result) {
    alert("Unable to retrieve dropdown values");
});
```

Now I want the Sun Group Types values to be dependent on selected Group Type value in drop down.

So , for example for the Sub Group Types second drop down , the result is a collection of objects like :

[image]

And for the Group Types drop down , the result looks like :

[image]

Now , only if the **"Chapter Event" from the Group Type drop down is selected** , then for that id , I want to select the values from the sub group types drop down where value has that id (5) concatenated.

Like **'Auction' should be displayed as value is 'Auction|5'** . Likewise , values should be displayed.

How would I do that ?

Also , by default on load , whatever group type is selected , the sub group type should be populated accordingly.

Please help.

Comment: are you looking to filter the the object?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are trying to filter the options of one select based on the selection from another.  To do this, you simply add a filter to the ng-options directive on the second select.  Like this:

```
ng-options="subGroupType.value for subGroupType in referenceAddRecord.subGroupTypes | filter: {id: referenceAddRecord.groupType.id} track by subGroupType.id"
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/tht12iBuBQ3UWB4pO6ZX?p=preview)